# How can we check the recent launch time of an app in Android?

Tags: android

I want to know the Recent launch time of an application in android?

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324847/launch-time-of-an-app

Comment: Dear go through this StackOverflow FAQ first: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Dear don't ask redundant question otherwise community will flag it or vote for close this kind of question.

Comment: Asking duplicate questions is not welcome behaviour here. If you aren't getting any good answers then please edit your question to add more information or place a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You can Log the System time in the onCreate of the Main Activity of the application. This time can be then set in a class level field and accessed from elsewhere in the application.
You could also have similar variable for onResume(..) etc

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    long launchTime;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        launchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to know the recent launch of other apps from my application.can it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is create a STICKY Service that tracks all of the running application.

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

    Timer timer  =  new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() 
        {
            final ActivityManager activityManager  =  (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<RunningTaskInfo> services  =  activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                 for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
                     if(!stalkList.contains(services.get(i).baseActivity.getPackageName()))
                     {
                          // you may store the time here  
                          stalkList.add(services.get(i).baseActivity.getPackageName());
                     }
                }

                 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {  

                    ArrayList<String> runningPkgs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(procInfos.get(i).pkgList));

                    Collection diff = subtractSets(runningPkgs, stalkList); 

                    if(diff != null)
                    {
                        stalkList.removeAll(diff);
                    }
               }


        }
    }, 20000, 6000);  // every 6 seconds


    return START_STICKY;
}
```