# Augmented Reality measurement technics/methods

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, augmented-reality

I am going to perform a comparative analysis against two AR application built respectively in:

1. **JavaScript** and **HTML5** (Mobile Web-App), and:
2. **Java** (Mobile App)

Could you please advise me as to what tools/methods should I use to measure things like:

- Application start time, or:
- Time needed to refresh the displayed 3D model

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

For **measurement of Application Start up time in Android** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124913/measure-android-app-startup-time).

For **measurement of page load time** see [here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20049/calculate-page-load-time-in-wireshark)

on Android you could use WebDevTools: See [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voltcode.webdevtools)