# Determine loading time for an android application

Tags: android, performance

Is there a way to determine the loading time for my android application.

- If there is then how can we measure this time in the most effective way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124913/measure-android-app-startup-time). Using adb for measuring load times

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that get called is the Application Constructor. So you can override the Application class and log the start time. After that, you can log again on the launcher activity's onResume() as this is the place where the app goes visible.