# What the best way to measure app/activity startup time?

Tags: android, startup

After googled this topic, I know there are several ways to measure the startup time of an android app.

1. adb logcat -b events | grep am_activity_launch_time, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124913/measure-android-app-startup-time)
2. adb logcat -s ActivityManager:I | grep Displayed
3. use reportFullyDrawn programmatically
4. adb shell screenrecord --bugreport /sdcard/launch.mp4, to check video frame by frame, see [this post](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2015/10/measuring-activity-startup-time.html)
5. adb shell am start -w packagename/MainActivity to check the output
6. adb logcat -s Timeline:I, to checkout "App_transition_ready" and Activity_windows_visible in the output.

What is the most precise way to measure startup time of an Android app? What are the differences among them?

Answer (score 3):

This is from **Official Android Documentation**

From API 19 onwards, logcat includes an output line containing a value called Displayed. This value represents the amount of time elapsed between launching the process and finishing drawing the corresponding activity on the screen. The elapsed time encompasses the following sequence of events:

1. Launch the process
2. Initialize the objects.
3. Create and initialize the activity.
4. Inflate the layout.
5. Draw your application for the first time.

Log line looks like this

```
ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming: +3s534ms
```

In order for this to work **disable filters in logcat view in android studio** because the system server, not the app itself, serves this log.

Check this official [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html) for further explanation about different methods.